# Qt splitter layout resize behaviour using Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have an issue with size in my view made in Qt with drag and drop.

Let me start with an image to help me explain

[image]

This is the mainwindow for my form.

What happens is:

We have 4 tab widgets. the left tab widget has a horizontal splitter to the 2 mid widgets.
The 2 mid widgets have a vertical splitter, and a horizontal splitter on the left and right side.

The right widget has a vertical splitter on its left hand.

So all views are connected using splitters.

Lastly the mainform sticks every thing together in a resizable way using horizontal layout.

The problem is, the width of the leftmost and rightmost widgets are fixed (in designer). 
I want them to be smaller in width. Something similar to:

[image]

You can see the widgets are resized. I was able to do this running the application, and manually adjusting the splitters. Is there a way in QtDesigner to do this? I tried playing with policies. I didn't really get any further however. Does this indicate a lack of knowledge of my part about policies? Perhaps layouts in general?

What options should I use to achieve the desired layout using QtDesigner. I want to avoid using code.

Hope I will be able to solve this soon. It must be overlooking something simple..

Comment: I'm using a splitter for the first time, and I don't see ANYTHING in the Designer that allows me to configure the position of the splitter.  I was going to attempt to set it via code in the constructor of the dialog (probably try to re-size the component on one side of the splitter to its minimum), but have not gotten there yet.  I'd be interested to hear what others have to say.

Comment: Glad to ehar im not the only one with this issue. It should be so simple. But setting size constraints like min-width etc do not seem to help for me.

Comment: Sizes can be set using [QSplitter's setStretchFactor function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/qsplitter.html#setStretchFactor). But as you have already noticed, it cannot be set in Qt Designer.

Comment: Stretch factor can be set in Qt Designer it falls under SizePolicy, horizontal stretch/vertical stretch. Or is that different from the method u are talking about?

Comment: Horizontal and Vertical Stretch under sizePolicy might be closely connected to the setStrechFactor function, but I can't get the same results by modifying Horizontal and Vertical Stretch values as compared to the setStrechFactor function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can play with the "Horizontal Stretch" and "Vertical Stretch" properties to change the position of the split.

For example with both the vertical stretch of the top central `QTabWidget` and the horizontal stretch of the central `QSplitter` at 1 and all the other values kept at 0, you'll get the result you want.

When you have multiple non-zero stretch values, the result of the ratio (e.g.: vertical strech at 2 and 1 for the 2 central `QTabWidget`s => 2/3 and 1/3) is not visible in the designer but seems to be working when you run the application.

**PS:** You can also achieve the same result with tabbified `QDockWidget`s but the dock tabbification is not possible through the designer only.

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple. I wwere right with the first one, mid widget and mid splitter to stretch 1 and it worked.

Comment: Just a small not for someone who may not find where to set "Horizontal/Vertical Stretch" in QtDesigner like me, these features are set under "Size Policy", which cannot be reached through search box directly

Answer (score 3):

I set start position that:

```
QList<int> list= ui->splitter->sizes();
list.replace(0,this->height()/0.3);
list.replace(1,this->height()/0.7);
ui->splitter->setSizes(list);
```

and remember to minimum size child widget