# QT Layout, Splitter and Widget Size

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout

I have a MainWindow in which I have three widgets inside two different splitters. Splitter1 contains two different widgets and Splitter2 contains Splitter1 and the black widget, as seen in the image.

It seems that QT has cleverly adjust the width of each widget to be 1/3 the total width of the outer containing object:

[how the window looks now](http://www.anothermessageboard.com/misc/window.png)

What I want is for the the black widget to be much smaller when the program launches and look something like this:

[how i want the window to look at startup](http://www.anothermessageboard.com/misc/window2.png)

I have played around with Size policies both in the Designer and progmatically. I have also tried progmatically setting the black widget's size when the program launches by calling blackWidget->resize(x,y) but that doesn't work either.

How can I make the default size of that widget smaller like I want?

Comment: Here's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650117/qt-splitter-layout-resize-behaviour-using-qt-designer. it's the same issue you had in your question.